# How to call a function from global API in Angular expressions?

Tags: angularjs

Angular.js provides a banch of global functions like angular.lowercase, angular.isArray etc.

Suppose I have a string in my scope:

```
function MyController($scope) {
   $scope.myString = "TEST"
}
```

Calling angular.lowercase has no effect:

```
{{lowercase(myString)}}
{{angular.lowercase(myString)}}
```

How can I call such function in my template?

**UPDATE**

Example with angular.isArray

```
<div ng-show="isArray(myVar)">...</div>
```

Comment: `{{myString | lowercase}}`  ..read filter docs

Comment: @charlietfl OK, it can be done with filter. I added another example, where the filter can't be used, I think.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The expression in the {{}} is not actual javascript although it looks that way - it's an angularjs [expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).  For this reason not everything will be available to you.

charlietfl is right that your particular case can be solved with an existing filter.  Not every angular.* function is exposed this way, however, in which case you should create your own custom filters.

Filters are cleanest but as a dirty workaround you could also just have the following line in your controller:

```
$scope.lowercase = angular.lowercase;  // not angular.lowercase()
```

Comment: This was recently downvoted - please let me know if there is something here that's inaccurate.  I wouldn't want to spread misinformation!

Comment: your answer is good for me, so yeah i don't know why someone would downvote you for this answer

Comment: Maybe the person didn't see that there isn't any pharanteses at angular.lowercase. This gave me a hard time to find... (type there something like // <- no () here alowed)